# Hook before fluid rendering or extending f:translation?

Tags: localization, typo3, hook, fluid, extbase

i want to implement my own localization tool over the typo3 database. Thus i implement a table with all localizations. But I have trouble to implement the functionality to render the label/localizations. Is there a hook, before normal rendering starts, so i can replace the fluid f:translation tag? Or can I extend the fluid f:translation helper?

I prefer the hook, but I am open to test something else.

best regards

Comment: So you want to modify the way `f:translation` works? Should it use your implementation of localization handling and have a fallback to it's standard behavior if no matching translation is found?

Comment: Have a look at Kerstins code, she did extend the translate view helper: https://gist.github.com/khuppenbauer/4702897

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though this document has seen its days, i find that it's still a very nice reference for hooks:
https://buzz.typo3.org/uploads/media/TYPO3_Frontend_Rendering_Process_v1.5.pdf

I suppose the one you're looking for is the **determineId-PostProc** hook.

Of course you can extend existing view helpers to your own namespace, not sure if you can overwrite existing core view helpers though.

Here's an article for extendind from an existing one (in German):
http://www.motions-media.de/2014/03/11/extbase-fluid-image-viewhelper-erweitern-fuer-lazyloading/

Comment: The hook with "deteminedId-PostProc" works great. The only problem is, that i have to load all keys into the array. At this moment, i do not know the necessary keys for the actual page.